# how to use onclick function when image button clicked?

Tags: php

i am trying to call a function when clicking an image button below but the function never fires. could any one tell me what i am doing wrong? is there any good jsfiddle type site that i show demo ?

```
    <script>
    function deleteLike(a,b)
    {
    alert("PageLink:"+a+"\nId:"+b);

    }
    </script>




    <?php

$i="23";
$pageLink="http://www.nba.com";

        echo '<div id="'.$i.'" style="float: right; padding: 5px 2px 2px;"> <img class="liker" onclick="deleteLike("'.$PageLink.'","'.$i.'")" src="http://cultureslurp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Facebook-Like-Button.jpg" border="0"></div>';

      ?>
```

Comment: You should read about unobtrusive javascript, your code is considered bad practice. It also makes things easier. See http://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing:

```
echo '<div id="'.$i.'" style="float: right; padding: 5px 2px 2px;"> <img class="liker" onclick="deleteLike(\''.$PageLink.'\',\''.$i.'\')" src="./liked.png" border="0"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have

```
onclick="deleteLike("");"
```

Instead use:

```
onclick="deleteLike('');"
```

Like this:

```
echo "<div id='$i' style='float: right; padding: 5px 2px 2px;'> <img class='liker' onclick=\"deleteLike('$PageLink','$i');\" src='http://cultureslurp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Facebook-Like-Button.jpg' border='0'></div>";
```

Comment: thanks for reply. how to declare variables inside it so it get passsed to function if i using your method ?

Comment: Just changed my answer with proper link.

Comment: If you use echo " " instead of echo ' ' you can store variables inside quotes. It makes you code easier to read without confusing .'\',\''.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easy and use jQuery and implement best practices.
Look at this code. Works also for people without javascript enabled!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.a-liker').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("PageLink: " + $(this).attr('href'));
            alert("Id: " + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="23" style="float: right; padding: 5px 2px 2px;">
    <a href="http://www.nba.com" class="a-liker">
        <img class="liker" src="./liked.png" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
```